# Is there a term for words that tend to be applied to one sex or the other?

Tags: phrase-usage

I don't mean explicitly but rather a connotation. One example is that in my experience, "affable" for some reason had only been applied to males. Irrespective of this example, I am asking for a term in linguistics maybe for such words.

Comment: 'Gender-orient(at)ed' is a term already in fairly common everyday use. I'd use it if the specific meaning were clear in a passage, but it's usually used to mean 'aimed/targeted at males/females' [marketing] or more generally 'specifically associated with men/males or women/females'.

Comment: Are "handsome" (male) and "pretty" (female) the kinds of words you're talking about?

Comment: You might want to ask in [linguistics.se].

Comment: @Barmar: Yes that is a clear example. But I think there are more subtle and arbitrary ones. I used to read a lot and I have seen many films and spoken to fellow humans and never heard someone say, What an affable woman! Friendly, yes, warm but not affable. This might be related to gender of nouns although I understand gender is pretty arbitrary in like German or Spanish.

Comment: I think this is more of a cultural thing, not linguistic. It's not the word that's gender-specific, but the concept it refers to.

Answer (score -1):

[Gender-specific](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gender-specific) (Merriam Webster Dictionary) referring only to males or only to females.

You can say "gender-specific terms".

Medical professionals use "sex-specifc" rather than "gender-specific".

Answer (score -1):

You could call such words **gendered,** [defined by The Free Dictionary as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Gendered)

> Having or making gender-based distinctions